# Estou com dificuldade para retornar meu ID usando o nextval, para posteriormente fazer o insert em minha tabela

Tags: c#, oracle, query, oledb

Estou com dificuldade para retornar meu ID usando o nextval, para posteriormente fazer o insert em minha tabela

```
     OleDbConnection cnx = new OleDbConnection(new AdministradorDAO().conexao);
     cnx.Open();

     string seq = ("select id_usuarios.nextval from dual");
     OleDbCommand cmdo = new OleDbCommand(seq, cnx);
     int id= (int)cmdo.ExecuteScalar(); 

     using (OleDbCommand cmd = cnx.CreateCommand())
     {
   // create command with placeholders
      cmd.CommandText = 
      "INSERT INTO USUARIOS"+
      "([ID], [MATRICULA],  [NOME], [SENHA], [NIVEL]),[MALETA],[EMAIL]) "+
      "VALUES(@id, @ma, @no, @se, @ni,@ma,@em)";

   // add named parameters
   cmd.Parameters.AddRange(new OleDbParameter[]
   {
       new OleDbParameter("@id", id),
       new OleDbParameter("@ma", txt_matricula.Text),
       new OleDbParameter("@no", txt_nome.Text),
       new OleDbParameter("@se", txt_senha.Text),
       new OleDbParameter("@ni", int.Parse(DropDownList_nivel.Text)),
       new OleDbParameter("@ma", int.Parse(txt_maleta.Text)),
       new OleDbParameter("@em", txt_email.Text),

   });

   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ao invés de passar o id como parâmetro você poderia colocar diretamente na sua instrução de insert.

```
cmd.CommandText = 
  "INSERT INTO USUARIOS"+
  "([ID], [MATRICULA],  [NOME], [SENHA], [NIVEL]),[MALETA],[EMAIL]) "+
  "VALUES(id_usuarios.nextval, @ma, @no, @se, @ni,@ma,@em)";
```

Comment: ainda continua com erro : Ocorreram um ou mais erros durante o processamento do comando.

ORA-00928: palavra-chave SELECT não encontrada

Comment: aluguem conseguiria me ajudar !!!

Comment: Eu passando a query no código, adiciona corretamente.
insert into usuarios (
        matricula
        , nome
        , sehna
        , nivel
        , maleta
        , email
    ) values (
        'TESTE'
        , 'Frederico'
        , 'TESTE'
        , 1
        , 7000
        , 'daerror@error.com.br'
    );

Answer (score 0):

O post é antigo mas talvez a solução ainda possa ser útil para alguém, segue:

Para fazer o carregamento do valor da sequence usando o Oracle e OleDb da forma que você fez esta correto de forma geral, o que pode estar acontecendo é o retorno do ExecuteScalar não estar permitindo o casting, faltou você dizer a exceção na linha do ExecuteScalar. Enfim como deve ser feito:

## Carregando o próximo ID

```
OleDbConnection cnx = new OleDbConnection("Provider = OraOLEDB.Oracle; Data Source = server001; User Id = XPTO_APLICACAO; Password=pas123");
cnx.Open();
string seq = ("select sq_atividade.nextval from dual");
OleDbCommand cmdo = new OleDbCommand(seq, cnx);
decimal id = (decimal)cmdo.ExecuteScalar();
```

O que é necessário verificar para que isto funcione:

- Conexão com o banco tem que estar OK.
- A sequence deve existir e estar visível para o usuário. Conforme já foi comentado.
- Retorno como decimal. No meu caso isto foi feito porque no banco o campo referente à minha chave que é incrementada pela sequence é decimal. Caso deseje saber o tipo faça: `object tipo = cmdo.ExecuteScalar().GetType();`. No se caso se não estiver disparando exceção de conversão então deixa o (int) mesmo.

## Montando o comando de INSERT

Veja que a diferença aqui é o uso de “dois pontos” na marcação dos parâmetros, funciona da mesma maneira. Se fizer com o “@” dispara erro de *ORA-00936: missing expression.* no exemplo acima, e se usar interrogação “?”, o erro é *ORA-00917: missing comma*.
Pode ocasionar erro também se os tokens SQL estiverem colados com outros caracteres, como por exemplo se não houver espaços entre o “values” e os parênteses, dispara o erro *ORA-00911: invalid character*.

Considerando que o passo anterior está ok, a montagem de parâmetros pode ser feita de duas formas:

**Primeira Forma - Direta**

```
cmd.Parameters.AddRange(new OleDbParameter[]
{
    new OleDbParameter(":v_ativ_cd_codigo", id),
    new OleDbParameter(":v_ativ_tx_descricao", "Atividade 3"),
    new OleDbParameter(":v_ativ_in_ativo", "S"),
    new OleDbParameter(":area_cd_codigo", 1),
});
```

**Segunda Forma – Criação de objetos separados**

```
OleDbParameter Parameter1 = new OleDbParameter();
Parameter1.OleDbType = OleDbType.Integer;
Parameter1.ParameterName = ":v_ativ_cd_codigo";
Parameter1.Value = id;

OleDbParameter Parameter2 = new OleDbParameter();
Parameter2.OleDbType = OleDbType.VarChar;
Parameter2.ParameterName = ":v_ativ_tx_descricao";
Parameter2.Value = "Atividade 2";

OleDbParameter Parameter3 = new OleDbParameter();
Parameter3.OleDbType = OleDbType.VarChar;
Parameter3.ParameterName = ":v_ativ_in_ativo";
Parameter3.Value = "S";

OleDbParameter Parameter4 = new OleDbParameter();
Parameter4.OleDbType = OleDbType.Integer;
Parameter4.ParameterName = ":area_cd_codigo";
Parameter4.Value = 1;
```

Das duas formas funciona, consegui cadastrar sem problemas, feito isso basta chamar o `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`;